# Review My H-Bridge Design?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, motor-controller

**Background Info:**
I need to drive two 24VDC brushed motors ([SDS4360-24-120F](https://www.transmotec.com/search/?s=SDS4360-24-120-F)) with a dual H-bridge circuit using 5V control signals. Initially a few [L298N module](https://lastminuteengineers.com/l298n-dc-stepper-driver-arduino-tutorial/) were used but they all eventually fried up sometime during operation. It all happened randomly whenever I sent the command to change rotation direction at full speed. The datasheet said the motor has a 5A peak startup current so I'm assuming that's what killed the L298N module.

**Alternative H-Bridge IC:**
From looking around, the only H-bridge ICs that met the voltage and current requirement are the MC339321VW/[MC33932VW](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/nxp-usa-inc/MC33932VW/2185659). The problem is that it's a bit pricey at $34.77 CAD per unit. So I decided to look into building my own H-bridge circuit using P-FET and N-FET.

**Initial Idea:**
I followed this video from [Afrotechmods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYafyPZ15g8&t=222s) and built a circuit in the picture below. The N-FETs are the [DMN3023L-7](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/DMN3023L-7/5453119) and the P-FETs are the [SSM3J372R,LF](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/SSM3J372R-LF/9866017). Both can handle a 30V difference between source and drain. From what I can find, the problem is the Vgs difference on the P-FET is too large. The difference can be as large as -24V compared to the -12V max rating on the datasheet. So I came up with this new design.
[image]

**Current Design:**
I added NPN BJTs in the current design (picture of it below). The idea is if IN1 is low, Q5 and Q6 are low (aka the switch is open). Thus, Vgs on P-FET is 0V so it's off (open) and Vgs on N-FET is 5V so it's on (closed). When IN2 is high, Q5 and Q6 are high. The gate on the P-FET is connected to voltage divider giving it around 20V which makes a Vgs of -4V. Thus the P-FET is on (closed). The gate of the N-FET is connected to ground and thus, it's off (open). **I can't seem to find any fault with this design. If you guys do please, let me know!**
[image]

Comment: 30 V FETs on 24 V supply sounds scary. What’s your 24 V tolerance? How much overshoot do you get when you flip polarity while spinning and does the FETs survive?

Comment: use separate base driving resistors, R4, R4', R8, R8'. If you are PWM-ing, you may want to drive FET-s with lower impedance than 10k or 5.1k.

Comment: Have you simulated the circuit in a simulator?

Comment: @winny. The 24V is from an industrial power supply. I measured it to be no more than 24.5V at most. Not sure if there is any overshoot when the current flow is flipped.

Comment: @jay I thought about that. What problems can occur if I don't? Would the BJT not turn on reliably?

Comment: @Justme No. I've never simulated a circuit design before.

Comment: On more, you want dead-time driving between Q1 & Q2, as well as Q3 & Q4. Otherwise, it will nicely smoke the FET-s and perhaps the power.

Comment: @Agriculex, yah, Q5 & Q7 never turn on.

Comment: Major mistake. Simulate everything you can!

Comment: Can i be blunt and suggest you scrap that circuit? Using 1K and 10k resistors to turn mosfets on and off means you will do that slowly. As well, there’s no current limiting, so you’ll end up frying the mosfets. Unfortunately designing a robust solution is not trivial and there’s the chip shortage to contend with - just about any chip with an automotive application is unobtanium at the moment. Some hints - 30V mosfets are too low voltage - go for 60-100V parts. Use a half h-bridge driver chip. Reversing a motor at full tilt will result in currents  in excess of 5A, so you need current limiting.

Comment: May I suggest simulating it yourself first? This Q&A site does not suite well for unspecified design reviews, but specific questions. I don't think you even have a question buried in there to answer.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for your input. It does put some perspective to the complexity of the H-bridge ICs. I'll probably scrap the circuit and just go with the MC33932 and bite the cost.

Comment: @Justme I'll look into how to setup and run simulations for future designs. I guess I made my question not clear and very much open ended. The question is basically asking people for feedback on my H-bridge circuit design.

Comment: @Agriculex, there are many other devices than the older freescale part. The price of it is too boocoo methinks. For 5A Infineon have some fully integrated half H bridge parts. The dev boards are probably  the only way to get them at the moment. Much less boocoo price wise.